# Android ListView does not refresh properly

Tags: java, android, listview

I use a ListView to show my items. When the items change I update the list of the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
MyAdapter adapter = (MyAdapter) myListView.getAdapter();
if(adapter == null) {
     adapter = new MyAdapter(this, itemList);
     myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This seems to work in a way since my ListView displays more items but the new items in the list do not get displayed properly.

These items do not show any information. It seems like the adapter did not refresh for these new items.

The adapter looks like this (simplified):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Point point = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null)
       convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_point, parent, false);

    TextView firstLine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
    firstLine.setText(point.getNumber());
}
```

[image]

Comment: Kindly check the console.The data are properly retrieved or not. If it is correct and check the size of the items.

Comment: The data is fine.

Comment: Maybe the data are not passed to the arraylist. Have you tried the adapter.notifyItemInserted(arraylistsize)

Comment: That is not it.

Comment: could you please post getView method of the adapter?

Comment: you are passing the data when adapter is null second time it will not be null as it contains data so listview will get empty items .

Comment: @RohanSharma: The list is a class variable and is still referenced by the adapter. I tried changing the list in the adapter directly but with the same result.

Comment: try to replace adapter==null with myListView.getcount>0

Answer (score 0):

invalidate your listView

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listView.invalidate();
```

Comment: No, did not work. Neither `invalidate()` nor `invalidateViews()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the data is not being passed to adapter when you are trying to notify data set changed. Can you post the whole class code where you are adding the data to your arraylist?
One other thing try to use "ViewHolder" class in your Adapter for views.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The updated items caused an exception early in the `Adapter.getView()` function due to soe missing additional data. So the rest of the function did not get called and left the content blank.

The solution is to not only update the list of the adapter but also all necessary additional data the adapter needs.

Comment: all's well that ends well :P